# Reverse for 'customuser-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

New user to Django, followed the basics for the DRF quick start. The main thing that I wanted to try was to make a custom user to not depend on the base model and add my custom fields to it. I did it and this is what I have:

custom_user.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from rest_framework import serializers

from snorlax.managers.custom_user_manager import CustomUserManager


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user to override default user."""

    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "CustomUser",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        db_column="created_by",
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault,
        related_name="%(class)s_created_by",
    )
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "CustomUser",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        db_column="updated_by",
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault,
        related_name="%(class)s_updated_by",
    )
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ("password",)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        """Define additional attributes."""

        db_table = "users"
```

user_view.py

```
from typing import Self

from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer

from snorlax.models import CustomUser
from snorlax.serializers.user_serializer import UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited."""

    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all().order_by("-id")
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def perform_update(self: Self, serializer: Serializer) -> None:
        """
        Update the model using the provider serializer..

        :param serializer: Serializer that will perform the save.
        :return: None.
        """
        serializer.save(updated_by=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self: Self, serializer: Serializer) -> None:
        """
        Create the model using the provider serializer..

        :param serializer: Serializer that will perform the save.
        :return: None.
        """
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user,
                        updated_by=self.request.user)
```

user_serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from snorlax.models import CustomUser


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the custom user."""

    class Meta:
        """Define the attributes that will be sent as response."""

        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            "url",
            "email",
            "groups",
            "id",
            "created_by",
            "created_datetime",
            "updated_by",
            "updated_datetime",
        ]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from snorlax.views.group_view import GroupViewSet
from snorlax.views.user_view import UserViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

test_custom_user.py

```
import json

import pytest
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory, force_authenticate

from snorlax.models import CustomUser
from snorlax.views.user_view import UserViewSet


@pytest.fixture
def test_user_email():
    return 'something@something.com'


@pytest.fixture
def admin_users():
    admin_1 = CustomUser.objects.create_superuser('admin@admin.com', "abcd")
    admin_1.updated_by = admin_1
    admin_1.created_by = admin_1

    admin_2 = CustomUser.objects.create_superuser('admin2@admin.com', "abcd")
    admin_2.updated_by = admin_2
    admin_2.created_by = admin_2

    return {
        "admin_1": admin_1,
        "admin_2": admin_2,
    }

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_update_user(test_user_email, admin_users):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    view = UserViewSet.as_view({
        "put": "update",
        "post": "create",
    })

    request = factory.post('/users/',
                           {
                               'email': test_user_email,
                           },
                           format='json')

    force_authenticate(request, user=admin_users["admin_1"])
    response = view(request)
```

This test fails on the last line:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'customuser-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<id>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'users/(?P<id>[^/.]+)/$']
```

Using the debugger all the way up to the serializer I can see that the third user is in fact created in the DB. I feel I am missing something silly here. How can I fix this?